# Title, x and y labels not showing up in plot using python console

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I am trying to plot median salaries by age with `matplotlib`. The code is as follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dev_x = [x for x in range(25, 36)]
dev_y = [38496, 42000, 46752, 49320, 53200, 56000, 62316, 64928, 67317, 68748, 73752]

plt.plot(dev_x, dev_y)
plt.title("Median salary (USD) by age")
plt.xlabel("Age")
plt.ylabel("Median salary (USD)")
plt.show()
```

When running this in `pycharm` as a file, it works as expected. However, the first time around, I was using the python console, the title, x and y label were not showing up. What would end up happening is when I would enter `plt.plot(dev_x, dev_y)`, the plot would show up. After that when I would add the title and axis labels, it would show an empty plot witch the individual elements. Furthermore, in the console `plt.show()` does nothing. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure()
plt.plot(dev_x, dev_y)
plt.title("Median salary (USD) by age")
plt.xlabel("Age")
plt.ylabel("Median salary (USD)")
f.show()
```